# Drupal form api file upload using drupal_http_request

Tags: forms, drupal, file-upload

I am trying to post a file uploaded in drupal form to another server through a post request using drupal_http_request.

I am not sure where am I making a mistake but the file doesnot seem to get posted. What should  I be doing.?

I use the following code.

```
 $options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => drupal_http_build_query($data),
  'timeout' => $connect_ariba_values['timeout'],
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data'),
);

$response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```

multipart/form-data  doesnot seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Source: https://drupal.org/user/194073

```
<?php 
$boundary = md5(uniqid());
$post_data = array(
  'name' => 'Ayesh',
  'file' => '/var/www/test/test.png',
);

$options = array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'data' => multipart_encode($boundary, $post_data),
  'timeout' => $connect_ariba_values['timeout'],
  'headers' => array('Content-Type' => "multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary"),
);
$response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);

// Function to encode text data.
function multipart_enc_text($name, $value){
  return "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"$name\"\r\n\r\n$value\r\n";
}

// Function to multipart encode a file from a give path.
function multipart_enc_file($path){
  if (substr($path, 0, 1) == "@") $path = substr($path, 1);
  $filename = basename($path);
  $mimetype = "application/octet-stream";
  $data = "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"$filename\"\r\n"; // "file" key.
  $data .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n";
  $data .= "Content-Type: $mimetype\r\n\r\n";
  $data .= file_get_contents($path) . "\r\n";
  return $data;
}

// base function to encode a data array.
function multipart_encode($boundary, $params){
  $output = "";
  foreach ($params as $key => $value){
    $output .= "--$boundary\r\n";
    if ($key == 'file'){
      $output .= multipart_enc_file($value);
    } else $output .= multipart_enc_text ($key, $value);
  }
  $output .="--$boundary--";
  return $output;
}
```

In the server, file will be available in `$_FILES['file']`, and other `POST` data will be available in their relevant keys.

I didn't test the code. I just found the code in drupal forum, changed it to work with Drupal 6 and 7.